# How to configure Breeze angularjs application with .net 6

Tags: breeze

I have followed this approch to create breeze server
https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-demo/tree/master/server/NorthwindNet5
It might be something i am not configuring correctly on breeze server itself, as in postman request too it is doing same things

I am trying to use Breeze with ODATA
https://localhost:5001/breeze/Cogito/GetAccessPoints?$select=Id,Name,Description,EndPointId,Type&

But it return all ODATA infrastructure as reponse
[enter image description here]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5YWA.png

```
services.AddControllers(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter()))
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                // Set Breeze defaults for entity serialization
                var serializerSettings = JsonSerializationFns.UpdateWithDefaults(options.SerializerSettings);
                if (serializerSettings.ContractResolver is DefaultContractResolver resolver)
                {
                    resolver.NamingStrategy = null;
                }
                serializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            })
            .AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents(
                   "breeze/Cogito",
                   model: OdataEdmBuilder.GetModel(),
                   batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler())
                       .Select()
                       .Expand()
                       .Filter()
                       .OrderBy()
                       .SetMaxTop(int.MaxValue)
                       .Count()
                       .SkipToken());
```

Comment: When do you get that exception?  On startup of the application?  Or when a query comes from the client?  What is the URL that comes from the client?  Did you configure your client as in https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-demo/tree/master/client/northwind-angular ?

Comment: Thanks steve schmitt for helping... on breeze server  config below things causes issues  with ODATA   .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
              {
             
                var serializerSettings = JsonSerializationFns.UpdateWithDefaults(options.SerializerSettings);
                if (serializerSettings.ContractResolver is DefaultContractResolver resolver)
                {
                    resolver.NamingStrategy = null;
                }
                serializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

Comment: Remove OData.  You need only the [BreezeQueryFilter] attribute on your controller in order to filter, select, expand, etc.